# Getting not authorized for query on testdb.system.indexes src/mongo/db/commands/find_cmd.cpp 170 in mongo 4.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongobee

I have recently upgraded to mongo `4.2.0` from `4.0.2`. On previous version user was able to access system.indexes but after upgrade, user is not able to access system.indexes collection. User already has readWrite role. Also, I tried giving dbAdmin but still no luck.

After enabling debug logs for mongo, it is showing me `not authorized for query on testdb.system.indexes src/mongo/db/commands/find_cmd.cpp 170`.

Anybody faced this issue?

Below is the output of

```
{
    "role" : "read",
    "db" : "testdb",
    "isBuiltin" : true,
    "roles" : [ ],
    "inheritedRoles" : [ ],
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "testdb",
                "collection" : ""
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "testdb",
                "collection" : "system.js"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "inheritedPrivileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "testdb",
                "collection" : ""
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "testdb",
                "collection" : "system.js"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 7):

I am able to fix this issue by creating a new role for system.indexes collection and attach this role to user.

```
db.createRole({role : "readWriteSystem", privileges: [{resource: { db: "testdb", collection: "system.indexes" }, actions: [ "changeStream", "collStats", "convertToCapped", "createCollection", "createIndex", "dbHash", "dbStats", "dropCollection", "dropIndex", "emptycapped", "find", "insert", "killCursors", "listCollections", "listIndexes", "planCacheRead", "remove", "renameCollectionSameDB", "update" ]}], roles:[]})
db.grantRolesToUser('testuser', ['readWriteSystem'])
```

Strange thing is, this issue happens when you upgrade mongo by **replacing binaries**.

I tried to have a fresh instance with 4.2 mongo installed and then replicating data to it, it worked fine. But I cannot do this on production due to some technical reasons.

---

Dear Mongo team,

I tried to upgrade mongo using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/#upgrade-replace-binaries, but got above issue. I think doc is missing few details related to `system.indexes` access related change

Comment: This solution is no longer functional...is there any new update please ?

Comment: Did you try solution on https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee/issues/104#issuecomment-743459023

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.9 of **Mongobee** is an older version on **MongoTemplate** witch has been discontinued from Mongo 4.2.

Extend the **Mongobee** class and update the **MongoTemplate** object to a newer **MongoTemplate** `constructor(MethodName -> "executeChangeSetMethod")`.
This resolved the problem for me without any changes in roles.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "system.indexes" is deprecated starting from mongo:4.2
[documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/#%3Cdatabase%3E.system.indexes)

We should use command ["list Indexes"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listIndexes/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.listIndexes) instead. But as of mongobee implementation we have

```
public Document findRequiredChangeAndAuthorIndex(MongoDatabase db) {
MongoCollection<Document> indexes = db.getCollection("system.indexes");
Document index = indexes.find(new Document()
    .append("ns", db.getName() + "." + changelogCollectionName)
    .append("key", new Document().append(ChangeEntry.KEY_CHANGEID, 1).append(ChangeEntry.KEY_AUTHOR, 1))
).first();

return index;
```

in the ChangeEntryIndexDao.class

So we can extend MongoBee and use some reflection to set extended ChangeEntryIndexDao with method overrided this way:

```
final ListIndexesIterable<Document> indexes = db.getCollection(changelogCollectionName).listIndexes();
            Document resultIndex = null;
            for (Document index : indexes) {
                final Document indexKey = index.get("key", Document.class);
                if (indexKey.containsKey(ChangeEntry.KEY_CHANGEID) && indexKey.getInteger(ChangeEntry.KEY_CHANGEID) == 1 &&
                        indexKey.containsKey(ChangeEntry.KEY_AUTHOR) && indexKey.getInteger(ChangeEntry.KEY_AUTHOR) == 1) {
                    resultIndex = index;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return resultIndex;
```

Comment: Please go through https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee/pull/106. It seems mongobee project is not maintained now